# Why does my code not insert the details to the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the following code to insert data into my database table, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have double and triple-checked the code and there are no errors at all. The console also doesn't show any as well.

I have not misspelled any of the details required to connect to the database and the variables are also correct so I am at a loss.

If anyone could help it would be be deeply appreciated.

My code:

```
<?php
function obfuscate($type, $data) {
    if ($type == "PIN"):
        $f_int = (int)md5($data);
        $data = str_split($data);
        $rev = implode("", array_reverse($data));
        $sum = array_sum($data) + $f_int;
        $data = implode("", $data);
        $data += $sum + $rev + 1026;

        // Keep the first four digits if the result is longer
        if (strlen($data) > 4):
            $data = substr($data, 0, 4);
        endif;
        return $data;
    elseif ($type == "password"):
        $data = password_hash($data, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 12]);
        return $data;
    endif;
}

function insert_user($username, $email, $password, $PIN, $Account_Type, $Account_Status, $Referrer, $Balance) {
    // Connect to the server and the database or show error
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't connect to the server.");
    mysqli_select_db($connection, "Calisoft_flu_db") or die("Couldn't connect to the database.");

    // Sanitise the data
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);
    $PIN = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $PIN);

    // Get the rest of the data
    $Registration_Date = date("Y-m-d");

    // Obfuscate password and PIN
    $password = obfuscate("password", $password);
    $PIN = obfuscate("PIN", $PIN);

    // Make query and insert data to database
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `PIN`, `Registration_Date`, `Account_Type`, `Account_Status`, `Referrer`, `Balance`) VALUES ('NULL', '$username', '$email', '$password', '$PIN', '$Registration_Date', '$Account_Type', '$Account_Status', '$Referrer', '$Balance')";
    $registered = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if ($registered) {
        echo "Register successful!";
    }
    // End the connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
}

insert_user("@user1", "user@gmail.com", "user12345678", "1234", "Member", "Active", "0", "0");
?>
```

Comment: Echo your query and run that query in mysql console and check the results.

Comment: Do you get `Register successful!`? You should check the status of the query as well.

Comment: Please please please. While it's still early, learn parameterized queries.

Comment: The mistake was adding putting NULL in ''. @PatrickGregorio, by parameterized queries, you mean preparing a statement and binding the parameters (eg. :username) like we do in PDO? Can this be done with mysqli? I prefer working with mysqli.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Yes, for mysqli try reading http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples and also read on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting a string value of 'NULL' into your primary key, you either remove the quotes '' or omit ID from the query.

**Remove Quotes:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `PIN`, `Registration_Date`, `Account_Type`, `Account_Status`, `Referrer`, `Balance`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password', '$PIN', '$Registration_Date', '$Account_Type', '$Account_Status', '$Referrer', '$Balance')";
```

**Or Remove the ID column:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `PIN`, `Registration_Date`, `Account_Type`, `Account_Status`, `Referrer`, `Balance`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$PIN', '$Registration_Date', '$Account_Type', '$Account_Status', '$Referrer', '$Balance')";
```

Comment: This answer is made possibly by the assumption that `ID` is not `varchar`, or any string-based column type. You're better to ask OP what column type `ID` is.

Comment: @Marcus he's right. In my case, ID is an auto-incremental integer and his solution works great. Thanks Shadi.

Comment: Good stuff. FYI @AngelPolitis, in the future, it pays off to provide as much relevant information as possible. In the case of database queries, providing the table schema in question can save a lot of time. Glad you got it sorted though.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus, I, indeed, had to be a little more thorough with my explanation of my issue.

Comment: Good point @Marcus, I should have verified the column type firstly.